# Creating an Orchard web application with customers, memberships, and silo-ing data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I have an idea on setting up an Orchard site that would provide "out-of-the-box" functionality like blogging, messaging, and calendaring.  Lets call this new web site coolApp.

Each customer would have there own domain like coolApp.somedomain.com and coolApp.someotherdomain.com.

I know that Orchard supports multi-tenancy so this is not a problem.  However, I want to make sure that at all times the users of coolApp.somedomain.com and coolApp.someotherdomain.com are not fetching each others data.  (This is a theme you will hear throughout this questions.)  So each CUSTOMER is silo-ed from the other customers.

Now each customer can setup groups.  Each group has a manager and it has members.  Each group gets the out-of-the-box functionality for its group.  The manager can blog, setup event calendars, and message, etc to HIS/HER group members only.  The manager can also setup other members to do the same.  But, as with customers, they cannot see other members group information and data.

However, the CUSTOMERS have the same out-of-the-box functionality to ALL its group managers and/or members all at once.  So a customer can message,blog, etc to all of its groups.

I think I would like it to work like this in terms of the http endpoints.  somedomain.com can do its blogging, messaging, etc from coolapp.somedomain.com.  Each group would do its blogging, messaging from coolapp.somedomain.com/group1, coolapp.somedomain.com/group2 etc.

One thing I did not mention is that some of the out-of-the-box functionality will be custom functionality for my use cases.  So it will not JUST do the blogging, calendar, etc but I will write custom modules.

And, of course, I would like all of this to be fairly automated.  Both in terms of setting up new customers (coolapp.somethirddomain.com) and, within each customer, make it easy to setup new groups.  (BTW, it is way more import that setting up new groups be easier than new customers.)

So, with all of that in mind, here are my questions.

1. How well does Orchard support that without any programming?  It seems that Orchard may be already setup to do that but I am not sure how.  What features do I need to study and understand to achieve that.
2. How do I write my custom module so that it will do the horizontally partitioning/siloing of the data.  What PROGRAMMING features do I need to understand to achieve that.
3. What advice can you give me about automating the creation of groups (new endpoints) in Orchard.
4. Any gotchas that I should be wary of.
5. I really want to do this in Orchard because I love Orchard and because I am a C# programmer.  But if Orchard is not a good fit, can someone recommend a .NET free (or almost-free) solution that would work better.

Thanks for your help.

Seth

Answer (score 3):

In Orchard each tenant can have its own database, which means the data storage can be siloed completely. Because this is the same app domain though, you must ensure a customer can't run custom modules, but just the ones you defined, which should be fine based on your description.

With multi-tenancy you can host different websites per domain and url prefix, even at the same time. This means that you can totally have different websites with their own databases on the same domain, with different prefixes:

app.domain1.com/group1 
app.domain1.com/group2 
app.domain2.com/group1 
app.domain2.com/group2

What you can even do, is to group all group websites of the same company in the same database using a table prefix. And all this comes for free, and you don't have to care about this when you create your module, AT ALL.

And you can run hundreds of tenants on a single Orchard install, literally hundreds. I have a POC with 1000 tenants on a large Azure Web Site instance, with hundreds of content items per database.